# in form tag change button/input option with select

Tags: javascript, html

while working on a project i face a problem using form_input_button. in the search bar i need to get 2 action in form like this `form action="http://www.youtube.com/results"` and `form action="https://torrentz.eu/search"`
but i did not find anything on the internet about this. i only need one `input` and one `button` to submit. but what i get is 3 `input` one for text and another 2 for `action` can any one have the answer. How i can use only one `input`  and one `button` showing. 
My Code:

````
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="search_query" type="text" maxlength="128" />
      <input type="submit" formaction="http://www.youtube.com/results" value="YouTube" />
      <input type="submit" formaction="https://torrentz.eu/search" value="TorrentZ" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: How do you want to switch between the two targets if you only have one input and one button?

Comment: How do you want to show both sites' search results then? In new tabs?

Comment: is it possible to switch through select option?

Comment: Yes, In new tabs? like `target="blank"` is it possible?

Comment: Use the code you have and `<form target="_blank">`

Comment: but can i show only one input and one button in `form` ?

Comment: In that case you need this: https://jsfiddle.net/mzLq0n5j/

Comment: search only goes to youtube i can't make the search change like using `select` for youtube and torrentz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this. You must listen to form submits and block them then you can open sites by selection

```js
document.querySelector('#searchForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  
  let searchQuery = document.querySelector('[name="search_query"]').value
  let selectedSite = document.querySelector('#selectSite').value
  
  window.open(
    selectedSite + searchQuery,
    '_blank'
  );

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="searchForm">
    <input name="search_query" type="text" maxlength="128" />
    <select id="selectSite">
      <option value="https://www.youtube.com/results?search">Youtube</option>
      <option value="https://torrentz.eu/search?search">Torrent Z</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you trying in code snippet directly run it does not work because it is in the sandbox. Please try in your project or HTML file.